# JavaFX - how to know if cancel was pressed

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, cancel-button

How can I know if the OK or the Cancel Button was pressed in this JavaFX dialog.

The Dialog Code:

```
public String delimiter;

public void delimiterYES() throws IOException {
    delimiter=new String();
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Delimiter");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Enter the delimiter");

    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent()) {
        delimiter=result.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Javadoc is not clear about this. Consider to file an issue: http://bugs.java.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a result is present, then the user pressed OK.  If no result is present, then the user probably pressed cancel, but they might have just closed the dialog window using the OS close window function.

```
Optional<String> result = new TextInputDialog().showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent()) {
    // ok was pressed.
} else {
    // cancel might have been pressed.
}
```

To really know if a button was pressed, you can use a filter as noted in the [Dialog javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) section "Dialog Validation / Intercepting Button Actions".

```
final Button cancel = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CANCEL);
cancel.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event ->
    System.out.println("Cancel was definitely pressed")
);
```

Sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;

public class DialogSample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button showButton = new Button("show");
        showButton.setOnAction(event -> showDialog(stage));
        showButton.setPrefWidth(100);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(showButton));
        stage.show();

        showButton.fire();
    }

    private void showDialog(Stage stage) {
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
        dialog.initOwner(stage);
        dialog.setTitle("Delimiter");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Enter the delimiter");

        final Button ok = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        ok.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event ->
            System.out.println("OK was definitely pressed")
        );

        final Button cancel = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        cancel.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event ->
            System.out.println("Cancel was definitely pressed")
        );

        Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Result present => OK was pressed");
            System.out.println("Result: " + result.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result not present => Cancel might have been pressed");
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answere here [JavaFX Dialogs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

**The result.isPresent() will return false if the user cancelled the dialog.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Optional<ButtonType>` instead of `Optional<String>`. And basically use the below code.

```
 Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent() &&  result.get()  == ButtonType.OK){
        System.out.println("Ok button is pressed");
    } else if(result.isPresent() &&  result.get()  == ButtonType.CANCEL){
        System.out.println("Cancel button was pressed");
    }
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you need any further clarification.